# How can i using my function inside function in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can I use my function inside the function in React JS? Here is the code:

```
function MyForm(props, ref) {

   fileSelectedHandler = event => {
      console.log(event);
   }

return (

  <div>
    <label htmlFor="file-icon">Upload icon</label>
    <input type="file" id="file-icon" onChange={this.fileSelectedHandler}/>
  </div>
)}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `onChange={fileSelectedHandler}` instead.

In using functional components, you don't really need to put `this` to refer to functions declared inside your component unlike class based component.